# Live control a float input with a regex mask

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I've made a function to live control numbers and float numbers.
But it doesn't work properly for float numbers, which have to be like this expression:

```
// I wish a number like x figures . 3 figures (example : 123456.123)
/^([1-9][0-9]*|0)(\.[0-9]{3})?$/
```

But this expression makes disappear the dot...

The follow works `/(^\d+$)|(^\d+\.\d+$)|[,.]/`, but multiple dots can be added:

```
$('.float_input').live("keypress",function(){inputControl($(this),'double');});

function inputControl(input,format) 
{ 
    var value=input.val();
    if (format=='int'){expression=/(^\d+$)|(^\d+\.\d+$)/;}
    else if (format=='double'){expression=/(^\d+$)|(^\d+\.\d+$)|[,.]/;}
    var values=value.split("");
    var update="";
    for(id in values)
    {           
        if (expression.test(values[id])==true && values[id]!='')
        {
              // also replace ',' by '.' 
              update=update+''+values[id].replace(',','.');
        }
    }
    input.val(update);
}
```

So I have multiple dots or no dot, it makes me nutty because I'm sure to be near the solution.

**EDIT > SOLUTION**

Ouch, thanks for the help about regex, I've found the solution!

Two tests were necessary:

- one for the characters test, tested one by one
- another to test the entire input while entering characters

This is the final script, which works like a flower, and I share it just for you:

```
$('.numeric_input').live("keyup",function(){inputControl($(this),'int');});
$('.float_input').live("keyup",function(){inputControl($(this),'float');});

function inputControl(input,format) 
{ 
    var value=input.val();
    var values=value.split("");
    var update="";
    var transition="";
    if (format=='int'){
        expression=/^([0-9])$/;
        finalExpression=/^([1-9][0-9]*)$/;
    }
    else if (format=='float')
    {
        var expression=/(^\d+$)|(^\d+\.\d+$)|[,\.]/;
        var finalExpression=/^([1-9][0-9]*[,\.]?\d{0,3})$/;
    }   
    for(id in values)
    {           
        if (expression.test(values[id])==true && values[id]!='')
        {
            transition+=''+values[id].replace(',','.');
            if(finalExpression.test(transition)==true)
            {
                update+=''+values[id].replace(',','.');
            }
        }
    }
    input.val(update);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex

> (/(^\d+$)|(^\d+.\d+$)|[,.]/)

should match

- 1111111   per the (^\d+$)
- or  111111.11111     per the (^\d+.\d+$)
- or  the comma followed by any character, and it could be anywhere in the expression.

I'm suspecting your regex should be
Note that I've escaped the final period.  That would match a comma or a period

> > /(^\d+[,\.]{0,1}\d{3})/

may be exactly what you want based on clarifications in the comments

> [-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+

would also work

NOTE: You can simplify your regex life tremendously by using Roy Osherove's [Regulazy](http://osherove.com/tools) or the tool Regex Buddy.

Comment: Admittedly, I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but your regex allows : "..........."
And I wish only one dot.
I wish, only : xnumbers . 3numbers (12345679.123)

Comment: [\.]{1}  should do the trick to make only one period,  \d{3} would be three digits.

Comment: This returns SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(^\d+[,\.]{0,1}\d{3}/: Unterminated group

Comment: Sorry - had my paren on the wrong side...  The other that I added may be more optimized, btw...

Comment: Those can't work with this script because it test the expression on each value with "for in", I may have to add this final expression after the individual test. Thank you anyway

Comment: Could you please give me the expression only for : 1 or 0 dot ?
To return true with : xx.xx and xxxx And false with : x.x.x or x....x
Then I could add it in the test of the global value like that : if(expression.test(values[id])==true && values[id]!='' && globalExpression(value)==true) where globalExpression = 1 or 0 dot regex

Comment: \.{0,1}   would represent one or zero dots, depending on the language.

Comment: Thanks but it returns true even if there are more than 1 dot.
I need : dot <=1 >> true and dot > 1 >> false

Comment: This is THE solution : /^([1-9][0-9]*\.?\d{0,3})$/ thanks for your help !

Comment: NP!  Again, I would heartily recommend you install Regulazy to figure these out :)  Btw, if you could accept the answer (click the checkmark) I'd really appreciate it.  Thanks!

Comment: +1 and checked, thanks a lot, I've tried Regulazy.
I've also edited the final script in my question, if it can help anyone too

Answer (score 0):

You want arbitrary amount of digits behind the decimal point (comma or period)?

What's wrong with:

```
/^([1-9][0-9]*|0)([\.,][0-9]+)?$/
```

I switched out the `{3}` for `+` and `\.` for `[\.,]`

Comment: This doesn't work also in the function. Dot is replaced by next numbers. I want : a number like x figures . 3 figures (example : 123456.123)