# How to allow only one decimal separator in the texbox?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, number-formatting

I have plugin . **You see demo at** :
 http://jsfiddle.net/nangvabien/8Uuvb/

If decimal separator = *"," or "."* , user input in the textbox :*1000000,,,,...5* --> format : *1.000.000,5* , or *12300000.,,..5* --> format *12,300,000.5*

I want to only decimal separator . Please help me improve plugin FormatNummer.

Answer (score 3):

I've done something that may help you :
[Live control a float input with a regex mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824439/live-control-a-float-input-with-a-regex-mask)

```
$('.numeric_input').live("keyup",function(){inputControl($(this),'int');});
$('.float_input').live("keyup",function(){inputControl($(this),'float');});

function inputControl(input,format) 
{ 
    var value=input.val();
    var values=value.split("");
    var update="";
    var transition="";
    if (format=='int'){
        expression=/^([0-9])$/;
        finalExpression=/^([1-9][0-9]*)$/;
    }
    else if (format=='float')
    {
        var expression=/(^\d+$)|(^\d+\.\d+$)|[,\.]/;
        var finalExpression=/^([1-9][0-9]*[,\.]?\d{0,3})$/;
    }   
    for(id in values)
    {           
        if (expression.test(values[id])==true && values[id]!='')
        {
            transition+=''+values[id].replace(',','.');
            if(finalExpression.test(transition)==true)
            {
                update+=''+values[id].replace(',','.');
            }
        }
    }
    input.val(update);
}
```

You can see it working here : http://jsfiddle.net/8Uuvb/1/

Comment: Hello Valky.  Your code is control input in the textbox, but i can't know how to add my code (here my code http://jsfiddle.net/nangvabien/8Uuvb/) to plugin FormatNumber right.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you really wanna do and why you want it, and what it may does finally. My post answers your title question. This expression /^([1-9][0-9]*[,\.]?\d{0,3})$/ allows only one decimal separator and 3 decimal after.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for decimal text field with a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dinopasic/xy1Ld7ob/). It works with negative numbers and copy/paste.

```
$('input').bind('paste', function () {
    var self = $(this);
    var orig = self.val();
    setTimeout(function () {
        var pasted = getTextDiff(orig, $(self).val());
        if(isNaN(Number($(self).val())))
            $(self).val($(self).val().replace(pasted, ''));
        console.log(pasted);
    });
});
$("input").keypress(function (event) {
    var inputCode = event.which;
    var currentValue = $(this).val();
    if (inputCode > 0 && (inputCode < 48 || inputCode > 57)) {
        if (inputCode == 46) {
            if (getCursorPosition(this) == 0 && currentValue.charAt(0) == '-') return false;
            if (currentValue.match(/[.]/)) return false;
        } 
        else if (inputCode == 45) {
            if (currentValue.charAt(0) == '-') return false;
            if (getCursorPosition(this) != 0) return false;
        } 
        else if (inputCode == 8) return true;
        else return false;

    } 
    else if (inputCode > 0 && (inputCode >= 48 && inputCode <= 57)) {
        if (currentValue.charAt(0) == '-' && getCursorPosition(this) == 0) return false;
    }
});
function getCursorPosition(element) {
    if (element.selectionStart) return element.selectionStart;
    else if (document.selection)
    {
        element.focus();
        var r = document.selection.createRange();
        if (r == null) return 0;

        var re = element.createTextRange(),
            rc = re.duplicate();
        re.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark());
        rc.setEndPoint('EndToStart', re);
        return rc.text.length;
    }
    return 0;
}
function getTextDiff(first, second) {
    var start = 0;
    while (start < first.length && first[start] == second[start]) {
        ++start;
    }
    var end = 0;
    while (first.length - end > start && first[first.length - end - 1] == second[second.length - end - 1]) {
        ++end;
    }
    end = second.length - end;
    return second.substr(start, end - start);
}
```